# Identify duplicate tags in Xml using XQuery/schema

Tags: xquery, xsd-validation, relaxng

I have an Xml fragment where I need to verify that there is only a single ocurrence of each node on the first level (0-based).

An example of bad Xml is this:

```
<library>
  <book1>
    <title>My first book</title>
    <PageNum>101</PageNum>
  </book1>
  <book2>
    <title>My second book</title>
  </book2>
  <book1>
    <title>Another of my first book</title>
  </book1>
  <book3>
    <title>My third book</title>
    <PageNum>101</PageNum>
  </book3>
</library>
```

... since there are two ocurrences of elements with element name "book1" at the first level.

The structure of the child-nodes is not important - just that there are no nodes with the same "top-level" element name. I also do not know the names of the child nodes.

How do I do this - using RelaxNg, XSD or XQuery?

Thanks,
Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath/XQuery you can compare whether the length of a sequence of all the tag names is of equal length than the length of a sequence of all *distinctive* tag names:

```
count(*/name()) = count(distinct-values(*/name()))
```

Comment: The return clause would look something like `if (count($library/*/name()) eq count(distinct-values($library/*/name()))) then 'there are no duplicates' else 'there are duplicates'`, with your xml stored in `$library`.